# How to get all the parameters(arguments) and their respective values including the optional ones, if any, of a built-in function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, parameters, built-in, htmlspecialchars

I'm using PHP **7.2.10**

I am using a built-in PHP function `htmlspecialchars()`

Following is my code :

```
<?php
  $new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
  echo $new;
?>
```

I want to pass all the parameters(arguments) of the function `htmlspecialchars()` in above code. The expected parameter list should include all the parameters including the invisible parameters(i.e. default parameters) with their respective values as mentioned [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-description)

Thank You.

Comment: `func_get_args` and `array_map` / `array_walk` perhaps?

Comment: I'm unclear what the purpose is. If you have explicit values you want to pass, just pass them. If you want to pass the default values… why? Simply not passing them will cause the default values to get used.

Comment: @deceze : I know the usage you are talking about but I want to know whether there is such mechanism exist in PHP that should give me all the parameters and their values(including the optional ones) passed to the built-in function. In my case to the built-in function `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no.

[`ReflectionFunction::getParameters`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php) and [`ReflectionParameter::getDefaultValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getdefaultvalue.php) *should* theoretically help here, but [they don't work for built-in functions](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28114).

```
var_dump(array_map(function ($p) { return $p->getDefaultValue(); }, 
                   (new ReflectionFunction('htmlspecialchars'))->getParameters()));
```

So, no. Read the manual, see what the default values are, and hardcode them in your code. Or just don't pass them at all, since that's pointless.